# Including column names in plot title when plotting with apply()

Tags: r

I am trying to make one plot per column of a data frame.  In the title of the plot, I would like to insert column name.  But it is not clear to me how to cycle through the column names.

```
`
snp1 <- runif(10,0,1)
snp2 <- runif(10,0,1)
snp3 <- runif(10,0,1)
snp4 <- runif(10,0,1)
pops <- paste('pop',1:10,sep='')
freq<- data.frame(snp1, snp2, snp3, snp4)
rownames(freq) <- pops
`

`freq
           snp1       snp2      snp3      snp4
pop1  0.4174916 0.16731405 0.3128548 0.8911312
pop2  0.6965112 0.38021753 0.9039974 0.7716086
pop3  0.6993367 0.35984906 0.5455272 0.4824148
pop4  0.5274188 0.23394308 0.8256183 0.5394379
pop5  0.1561838 0.57830706 0.3515259 0.9654348
pop6  0.1712315 0.05702597 0.2600516 0.7401471
pop7  0.6950924 0.15866269 0.1411592 0.3601718
pop8  0.1360697 0.96311812 0.3862654 0.5717191
pop9  0.4941322 0.63638984 0.3307210 0.5176871
pop10 0.1986985 0.63893809 0.9380498 0.2106029
`

`
library(ggplot2)
pdf('snp_plots.pdf')
apply(freq, 2, function(x) qplot(1:10, x, ylim=c(0,1), main=colnames(freq)))
dev.off()
`
```

Comment: Please, try to reshape fron wide to long format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map2` from `purrr` instead of `apply`.

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
map2(.x = freq, .y = names(freq), ~qplot(1:10, .x, ylim = c(0, 1), main = .y))
```

**EDIT**

We can use `purrr::imap` instead, which is short hand for `map2(x, names(x), ...)`

```
imap(.x = freq, ~qplot(1:10, .x, ylim = c(0, 1), main = .y))
```

Comment: If the data was instead in rows, how would this code change?

Comment: @cryptic0 please ask a new question and provide a reproducible example.